# Can't get the data from a post request in a node app behind a nginx reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a node.js app behind a nginx reverse proxy and I can't get the data when I make a POST request (using a REST Easy addon for firefox). I look up in the site and I can't find something useful. Here is my code.

nodetest.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/test', function (req, res){
  var p1 = req.body.param1;
  var p2 = req.body.param2;
  res.send('param1: '+p1+' param2: '+p2+' ');
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(8081, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8081!');
});
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name funklipe.cl;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_buffering off;
        }
}
```

I use pm2 for run the node app

```
pm2 start nodetest.js
```

when make the post request (with param1=foo and param2=var) I get

```
param1: undefined param2: undefined
```

I hope you can help me, if you need more info just let me know

Thanks in advance

Comment: the above works on my machine, what does your nginx conf look like? are you importing the default within the http block? And are you using form-urlencoded in your POST body when you make your post request?

Comment: I didn't make changes to the conf, the problem was about the headers, it seems the addon I used doesn't set the header properly, so I will use curl from now. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nginx config seems OK to me.

At your client side, make sure that you set the header properly. For example:

If you specify `application/json`:

```
$ curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"param1": "this_is_param1", "param2": "this_is_param2"}' http://localhost:8081/test
param1: this_is_param1 param2: this_is_param2
```

If you specify `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
$ curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d param1=this_is_param1 -d param2=this_is_param2 http://localhost:8081/test
param1: this_is_param1 param2: this_is_param2
```

But if you don't specify the header, then the client will use the default. And the behavior will be unexpected:

```
$ curl -X POST -d '{"param1": "this_is_param_1", "param2": "this_is_param2"}' http://localhost:8081/test
param1: undefined param2: undefined
```